# why do I keep getting a "displaymessage is not defined" error message?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell me why I keep getting a "displaymessage is not defined" error message with this code.. Thanks in advance :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TEST PAGE</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

function displaymessage() {
    alert("Hello World!");
    }

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p><input type="button" name="start" id="start" value="start" onclick="displaymessage()" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your `displayMessage` function in a DOM Ready callback - which means that it will be defined when ...well... the DOM is ready. And yet - you add it as a handler to a click of a DOM element - something that will be processed **before** the function is actually defined.

Move the definition out of `$(document).ready(function(){...}` and you'll be OK.

Additionally, the preferred way of binding handlers to various DOM events is programmatic, rather than declarative. Instead of adding an `onclick` attribute to your button you should rewrite the entire thing to something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

...

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

function displaymessage() {
    alert("Hello World!");
}

$('#start').on('click', displaymessage);

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p><input type="button" name="start" id="start" value="start"/></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great - that worked: Move the definition out of $(document).ready(function(){...}.. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

Scope. Your function is declared within the scope of the `onload` function so that is the only place you would be able to access it. To access it from other places, move it outside the `$(document).ready` function.

Answer (score 0):

why do you write inside the document ready function. Just write outside it should like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function displaymessage() {
    alert("Hello World!");
    }


</script>
```

Comment: The actual script I will be using will have jquery in it. Example:

    function removeAjaxSpinnerFunction(){
        $("#AjaxSpinner").remove();
    }